# Haskell: Best way to turn a list of tuples into a haskell function?

Tags: list, function, haskell

i have a list of triples of strings like this:

```
mylist = [("a1","a2","a3"), ("b1","b2","b3"), ("c1","c2","c3")]
```

The actual strings are arbitrary, except that the list represents a binary function that maps the first two strings to the third. What is a computationally fast way to implement a function

```
f :: String -> String -> String
```

so that

```
f "a1" "a2" == "a3"
f "b1" "b2" == "b3"
f "c1" "c2" == "c3"
```

And also, is there a general way to do this with a list of tuples?

So far, i only came up with

```
f a b = lookUp (a,b) [ ((x,y),z) | (x,y,z) <- mylist ]
```

Thanks,
André

Comment: What solutions have you tried to implement?  You can usually learn more if you come in with an attempted solution.

Comment: What is wrong with using a map from tuples of strings to strings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is usually done with a map (see [`Data.Map`](http://learnyouahaskell.com/modules#data-map), that link also explains how it works and how to build your own map).

You'll likely need to use a `([Char],[Char])` as key, so your data could be represented this way:

```
[(("a1","a2"),"a3"), (("b1","b2"),"b3"), (("c1","c2"),"c3")]
```

Comment: Thanks peoro. I didn't know about this yet. Just learning Haskell.

Comment: If you want a faster way then use [HashMap](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/unordered-containers/0.1.0.0/doc/html/Data-HashMap-Strict.html).

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit unclear *what* you want this function to do. If it is an arbitrary mapping of two inputs to one output, then go with peoro's suggestion of using `Data.Map`. If the computation has some systematic meaning, then try to discover the algorithm behind it.

```
import Data.Char
incStr [c,x] | isNumber x = [c, intToDigit (digitToInt x + 1)]
```

---

```
ghci> incStr "a1"
"a2"
```